# Get months between two years and get sum of all months per year

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I want to get all the months between two years and that months between two years  all of their data will be totaled to get the sales for each year.

Here is the screenshot of my table:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI1Wv.png)

For example I want to get yearly sales from 2016 to 2017, I need to sum all of the columns that have year 2016 and 2017 in the name to that I can get the yearly sales. I know that this table is not normalize or normal for that matter. But this table is not mine.

Here is my sample code for getting the months between two dates:

```
$start = new DateTime($_POST["start"]);
$end = new DateTime($_POST["end"]);

$smonth = (int)$start->format('Y')*12+(int)$start->format('n');
$emonth = (int)$end->format('Y')*12+(int)$end->format('n');

$firstmonth = min($smonth, $emonth);
$lastmonth = max($smonth, $emonth);
$months = array();

for ($i = $firstmonth; $i <= $lastmonth; $i++) {
    $thism = new DateTime(sprintf('%04d-%02d-01', intdiv($i, 12), $i % 12));
    $months[] = strtoupper($thism->format('M_Y'));
}

$m_total = implode(',', preg_replace('/^(.*)$/', 'SUM($1) AS $1', $months));
$m_average = implode(',', preg_replace('/^(.*)$/', 'AVG($1) AS $1', $months));
```

Comment: Good to see an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811919/subtract-start-and-end-dates-php/49812296#49812296) getting re-used. But not clear exactly what you're asking. Do you want the sum of the sales for 2016 and 2017 together, or the sum of the sales for 2016, and the sum of the sales for 2017? Likewise with your average code.

Comment: @Nick I want to get the all of the months of 2016 and 2017 and total all of that months for each year. Meaning I need to sum all months form JAN_2016 to DEC_2016 in order to get yearly sales of 2016 and same goes for 2017, 2018, etc.

Comment: @Nick BTW your answer helped me alot thank you

Comment: @Nick please help

Comment: @Nick Can you help me to get the years between two dates and format the output into this (SUM(JAN_2017)+SUM(FEB_2017) AS 2017?

Comment: Do you want `SUM(JAN_2017, ..., DEC_2017) AS SUM2017` or `SUM(JAN_2017)+SUM(FEB_2017)+...SUM(DEC_2017) AS SUM2017`?

Comment: (SUM(JAN_2017)+SUM(FEB_2017)+...SUM(DEC_2017)) AS 2017 sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you want.

```
$start = new DateTime('2016-04-20');
$end = new DateTime('2018-03-02');

$smonth = (int)$start->format('Y')*12+(int)$start->format('n');
$emonth = (int)$end->format('Y')*12+(int)$end->format('n');

$firstmonth = min($smonth, $emonth);
$lastmonth = max($smonth, $emonth);

$months = array();
$m_totals = array();

for ($m = $firstmonth; $m <= $lastmonth; $m++) {
    $year = intdiv($m, 12);
    $thism = new DateTime(sprintf('%04d-%02d-01', $year, $m % 12));
    $months[] = strtoupper($thism->format('M_Y'));
    if ($m % 12 == 0) {
        //      $m_totals[] = 'SUM(' . implode(',', $months) . ') AS SUM' . ($year - 1);
        $m_totals[] = 'SUM(' . implode(') + SUM(', $months) . ') AS SUM' . ($year - 1);
        $months = array();
    }
}
if (count($months)) $m_totals[] = 'SUM(' . implode(') + SUM(', $months) . ') AS SUM' . $year;
$m_total = implode(', ', $m_totals);
echo "$m_total\n";
```

For the start and end dates that I have used, this will output:

```
SUM(APR_2016) + SUM(MAY_2016) + SUM(JUN_2016) + SUM(JUL_2016) + SUM(AUG_2016) + SUM(SEP_2016) + SUM(OCT_2016) + SUM(NOV_2016) + SUM(DEC_2016) AS SUM2016,
SUM(JAN_2017) + SUM(FEB_2017) + SUM(MAR_2017) + SUM(APR_2017) + SUM(MAY_2017) + SUM(JUN_2017) + SUM(JUL_2017) + SUM(AUG_2017) + SUM(SEP_2017) + SUM(OCT_2017) + SUM(NOV_2017) + SUM(DEC_2017) AS SUM2017,
SUM(JAN_2018) + SUM(FEB_2018) + SUM(MAR_2018) AS SUM2018
```

To get all months of the start and end years, just change these lines:

```
$smonth = (int)$start->format('Y')*12+1;
$emonth = (int)$end->format('Y')*12+12;
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will do this and get back to you

Comment: I can only get the data from march in 2018 not from january to december?

Comment: I want to get the months from Jan to Dec regardless of the month of start or end date

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

At some point you will live to regret having a table that is so awkward to query from. I don't know if you want to exploit dynamic sql for this, but the following *might* be useful.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fd132/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`DEC_2016` int, `JAN_2017` int, `FEB_2017` int, `MAR_2017` int, `APR_2017` int, `MAY_2017` int, `JUN_2017` int, `JUL_2017` int, `AUG_2017` int, `SEP_2017` int, `OCT_2017` int, `NOV_2017` int, `DEC_2017` int, `JAN_2018` int, `FEB_2018` int, `MAR_2018` int, `APR_2018` int, `MAY_2018` int, `JUN_2018` int, `JUL_2018` int, `AUG_2018` int, `SEP_2018` int, `OCT_2018` int, `NOV_2018` int, `DEC_2018` int, `JAN_2019` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`DEC_2016`, `JAN_2017`, `FEB_2017`, `MAR_2017`, `APR_2017`, `MAY_2017`, `JUN_2017`, `JUL_2017`, `AUG_2017`, `SEP_2017`, `OCT_2017`, `NOV_2017`, `DEC_2017`, `JAN_2018`, `FEB_2018`, `MAR_2018`, `APR_2018`, `MAY_2018`, `JUN_2018`, `JUL_2018`, `AUG_2018`, `SEP_2018`, `OCT_2018`, `NOV_2018`, `DEC_2018`, `JAN_2019`)
VALUES
    (1000, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 100)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
set @start := '2017-01-15'

select concat(
   'select '
  ,(select group_concat(' ', fn, ' as ', fn)
    from (
    select concat(upper(left(DATE_FORMAT(dt, "%M"),3)),'_',DATE_FORMAT(dt, "%Y")) fn
    from (
          SELECT
               n, DATE_FORMAT(@start, '%Y-%m-01') + interval n MONTH AS dt
          from (
               select 0 n union all  select 1 n union all  select 2 n union all  select 3 n union all  select 4 n union all  select 5 n union all  select 6 n union all  select 7 n union all  select 8 n union all  select 9 n union all  select 10 n union all  select 11
               ) d1
          ) d2
      ) d3
    )
  , ', ('
  ,  replace(
    (select trim(LEADING ' + ' from group_concat(' + ', fn))
      from (
      select concat(upper(left(DATE_FORMAT(dt, "%M"),3)),'_',DATE_FORMAT(dt, "%Y")) fn
      from (
            SELECT
                 n, DATE_FORMAT(@start, '%Y-%m-01') + interval n MONTH AS dt
            from (
                 select 0 n union all  select 1 n union all  select 2 n union all  select 3 n union all  select 4 n union all  select 5 n union all  select 6 n union all  select 7 n union all  select 8 n union all  select 9 n union all  select 10 n union all  select 11
                 ) d1
            ) d2
        ) d3
    ), ',','')
  , ') as Y1, '
  , (select group_concat(' ', fn, ' as ', fn)
    from (
    select concat(upper(left(DATE_FORMAT(dt, "%M"),3)),'_',DATE_FORMAT(dt, "%Y")) fn
    from (
          SELECT
               n, DATE_FORMAT(@start, '%Y-%m-01') + interval n MONTH AS dt
          from (
                 select 12 n union all  select 13 n union all  select 14 n union all  select 15 n union all  select 16 n union all  select 17 n union all  select 18 n union all  select 19 n union all  select 20 n union all  select 21 n union all  select 22 n union all  select 23
               ) d1
          ) d2
      ) d3
    )
  , ', ('
  ,  replace(
    (select trim(LEADING ' + ' from group_concat(' + ', fn))
      from (
      select concat(upper(left(DATE_FORMAT(dt, "%M"),3)),'_',DATE_FORMAT(dt, "%Y")) fn
      from (
            SELECT
                 n, DATE_FORMAT(@start, '%Y-%m-01') + interval n MONTH AS dt
            from (
                 select 12 n union all  select 13 n union all  select 14 n union all  select 15 n union all  select 16 n union all  select 17 n union all  select 18 n union all  select 19 n union all  select 20 n union all  select 21 n union all  select 22 n union all  select 23
                 ) d1
            ) d2
        ) d3
    ), ',','')
 , ') as Y2 '
 , ' from table1'
 ) as the_sql
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fd132/1/1)**:

```
| the dynamically generated sql is:
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| select  JAN_2017 as JAN_2017, FEB_2017 as FEB_2017, MAR_2017 as MAR_2017, APR_2017 as APR_2017, MAY_2017 as MAY_2017, JUN_2017 as JUN_2017, JUL_2017 as JUL_2017, AUG_2017 as AUG_2017, SEP_2017 as SEP_2017, OCT_2017 as OCT_2017, NOV_2017 as NOV_2017, DEC_2017 as DEC_2017, (JAN_2017 + FEB_2017 + MAR_2017 + APR_2017 + MAY_2017 + JUN_2017 + JUL_2017 + AUG_2017 + SEP_2017 + OCT_2017 + NOV_2017 + DEC_2017) as Y1,  JAN_2018 as JAN_2018, FEB_2018 as FEB_2018, MAR_2018 as MAR_2018, APR_2018 as APR_2018, MAY_2018 as MAY_2018, JUN_2018 as JUN_2018, JUL_2018 as JUL_2018, AUG_2018 as AUG_2018, SEP_2018 as SEP_2018, OCT_2018 as OCT_2018, NOV_2018 as NOV_2018, DEC_2018 as DEC_2018, (JAN_2018 + FEB_2018 + MAR_2018 + APR_2018 + MAY_2018 + JUN_2018 + JUL_2018 + AUG_2018 + SEP_2018 + OCT_2018 + NOV_2018 + DEC_2018) as Y2  from table1 |
```

**[when that is executed, then:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fd132/1/2)**:

```
| JAN_2017 | FEB_2017 | MAR_2017 | APR_2017 | MAY_2017 | JUN_2017 | JUL_2017 | AUG_2017 | SEP_2017 | OCT_2017 | NOV_2017 | DEC_2017 | Y1 | JAN_2018 | FEB_2018 | MAR_2018 | APR_2018 | MAY_2018 | JUN_2018 | JUL_2018 | AUG_2018 | SEP_2018 | OCT_2018 | NOV_2018 | DEC_2018 | Y2 |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----|
|        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 | 12 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 | 12 |
```

Comment: can you make it simpler I just want to get this format (SUM(JAN_2017)+SUM(FEB_2017+ SO ON) AS 2017, SO ON